# How to remove unicode control characters from a string in Go before decoding JSON

Tags: json, string, go, unicode

I want to create a function which does the same as `json.Unmarshal`, but before that it needs to remove all JSON encoded unicode control characters which are not spaces.

```
func UnmarshalJSON(data []byte, v interface{}) error {
    // TODO: implement the removeControlCharacters function
    // cleanData, err := removeControlCharacters(data)
    // if err != nil { return err }

    return json.Unmarshal(cleanData, v)
}
```

I already got that same removal function working for characters which are not JSON encoded like so:

```
cleanData := strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
    if unicode.IsControl(r) && !unicode.IsPrint(r) && !unicode.IsSpace(r) {
        return -1
    }
    return r
}, string(data))
```

However, in JSON these characters are encoded like `\u0000`. Also there's the problem of having escaped slashes. So when the JSON data (as a string) looks like this:

```
{"name":"\b\t\u0009Some\u0000thing\\u0002"}
```

I expect an output like this (also as a string):

```
{"name":"\t\u0009Something\\u0002"}
```

Is there a way to remove these characters in a relatively clean way? Is there some preexisting code somewhere which I could use? It's a bit annoying to create very low level code for something quite basic (in my opinion)

Comment: If you're trying to follow the same encoding/decoding rules as `json`, why not just use the `encoding/json` package itself?

Comment: It is not the same decoding as json, because it has to omit unicode control characters which are not spaces. The unicode null character causes postgres to throw errors for example. Also it has to be a generic function, so that I don't have to worry about these characters at every single endpoint. So the shape of the json data is unknown

Comment: I think you may have something other formatting issue misleading you here. There is no special "unicode null character" in this example, `\u0000` is encoded exactly the same as `\x00`, it's just a matter of how you are formatting the string, but it's only an integer `0` either way.

Comment: This is the character I'm referring to https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0000 . I know it can be formatted both as `\u0000` or `\x00`. Honestly I do appreciate that you're trying to help, but I don't think you actually read the question correctly

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect to decode `\t` and `\u0009` differently, when they represent the same rune, but otherwise your `strings.Map` seems to do exactly what you want https://go.dev/play/p/0etGSMy0t1t

Comment: I changed your example a bit in here: https://go.dev/play/p/GDme1qCZlEv . I hope this makes sense. I try to remove the unicode characters before calling `json.Unmarshall` :)

Comment: If that's the case, trying to pre-process the json as a simple string before decoding the json seems very error prone, because you have no context about the quotes or data structure you're currently decoding. The string is encoded json, so the package which will process all the quoting and escaping rules correctly is `json`. It may not be impossible to blindly preprocess the json as a partially double-quoted string, but it would be far easier to clean the string after decoding the json.

Comment: I know it is tempting to come to that conclusion, and indeed it usually is easier, but the reason why I think cleaning before decoding makes more sense in this case is because the interface to which the data is being decoded (`v interface{}` in the code above) could contain recursive pointers. To clean the strings after decoding you would have to check every field with the reflect package and prevent recursion.

Comment: And also, I don't think a backslash could be part of anything in json but a string, so you don't really have to worry about the rest of the context. Still, I understand it sounds counter intuitive, but the alternative isn't really that good either

Comment: Decoding json into default types will never result in recursive pointers, because json has no references. Yes, since a backslash will only be in a quoted string, you can skip parsing strings and check each backlash character and see if the following characters can form a valid escape sequence, then rewrite it and and re-escape the result (being careful not to generate any `"` from escapes like `\u0022` or `\x22` or course). There's not likely ready-made code to do this, because parsing only the quoted strings from within encoded json is not something one normally ever does.